# Reading first few characters from Arduino serial input

Tags: android, string, bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to separate four functionalities by comparing inputs text from android to Arduino. For that I wrote a small piece of code as follows:

```
//Input string
String inStr = "";
char inChar;
int x = 0;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(inStr == "st") { Serial.print(inStr); inStr = ""; x = 0; }
  if(inStr == "sp") { Serial.print(inStr); inStr = ""; x = 0; }
  if(inStr == "cc") { Serial.print(inStr); inStr = ""; x = 0; }
  if(inStr == "cb") { Serial.print(inStr); inStr = ""; x = 0; }
}

void serialEvent() {
  while(Serial.available()) {
    if(x < 2) {
       inChar = Serial.read();
       inStr += inChar;
  }
  Serial.print(inStr); //Just to debug
}
```

It gives me fine input for buttons which send "sp", "cc", "cb" from android application. But the button which sends "st" also sends time from android, i.e. total string it sends is "st22:00:11" (Taking 22:00:11 as time, for instance). This string is what I am trying to break to "st" but my code is unable to.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the code is simply 2 letters at the start of the input string, you can substring the input string:

```
String extractedStr = inStr.substring(0,2); //This is the first 2 letters
```

Comment: I don't want to use external library for this, can you suggest elementary way to solve?

Comment: This is all in the Java SDK: [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Comment: As far as I know Arduino doesn't support these as such. Java SDK? I am little confused.

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood your question then, are you parsing these strings in the android app or on your arduino?

Comment: I am parsing these strings on arduino

Comment: I thought that you were parsing in the android app. I will update my answer

Comment: Commenting on your update, this is what I did as an alternative to it, but the problem occurred was, it gave me output as "ssssss" for "st22:00:11" (number of s' are equal to characters fetched from android). I have no idea why.